# My else statement is not echoing the variable

Tags: php, if-statement, echo

It's written in PHP. 
My if is working fine, but my else is not echoing. $start and $end are working variables.

```
   <select name="trip" class="select-trip">
  <?php foreach ( $wp_trips as $trip ) {
    if ($trip->available && $is_day_trip){
         $start = date_i18n("d/m/Y", strtotime($trip->start_date));
         $end = date_i18n("d/m/Y", strtotime($trip->end_date));?>
        <option value="<?php echo $trip->remote_ID; ?>">
        <?php echo $start;
      } else {
          echo $start . ' T/M ' . $end;
      }
    } ?>
  </select>
```

Comment: Which variable should it print?

Comment: you declare the `$start` and `$end` variables in the if conditional block. Your else statement doesn't get these - however as you're in a foreach loop, if previously set then it will take values from the **last** iteration - which could lead to unexpected behaviour

Comment: Also Print the o/p of `$wp_trips`

Comment: You declare and assign a value to `$start` and `$end` only in the IF. So if you get to the ELSE those 2 variables do not exist

Comment: @NicoHaase echo $start . ' T/M ' . $end;. the $end and $start variables.

Comment: Looks like you are running with error reporting turned OFF! Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php/845025#845025) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: And if you are using `mysqli_` also add `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should declare your `$start` and `$end` variables before if statement and you should put your `option` tag before `if statement` and also close it after `if statement`

```
<select name="trip" class="select-trip">
<?php 
foreach ( $wp_trips as $trip ) {
    $start = date_i18n("d/m/Y", strtotime($trip->start_date));
    $end = date_i18n("d/m/Y", strtotime($trip->end_date));
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $trip->remote_ID; ?>">
       <?php
          if ($trip->available && $is_day_trip){
             echo $start;
          } else {
             echo $start . ' T/M ' . $end;
          }
        ?> 
    </option> 
    <?php
} 
?>
</select>
```

Comment: the variables are in `$trip` object so they can not be empty as my view. as he is checking  if trip is of one day or more in if statement so he is printing only startdate in if and both in else.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in this code is $start and $end has only scope with in that if statement. For getting the value of $start and $end outside the if statement, variable declaration should obviously been done outside the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

As example you can do it like this one:

```
foreach ($wp_trips as $trip) {
        $checker = $trip->available && $is_day_trip;
        $start = '';
        $end = '';
        if ($checker) {
            $start = date_i18n("d/m/Y", strtotime($trip->start_date));
            $end = date_i18n("d/m/Y", strtotime($trip->end_date));
        }

        if ($checker && !empty($start)) {?>
            <option value="<?php echo $trip->remote_ID; ?>">
                <?php echo $start;?>
            </option>
        } else {
            echo $start . ' T/M ' . $end;
        }
    }
```

Comment: what's the point with checking twice? why not have the option stuff in the first $checker to begin with? Also this would be invalid as it's not creating an option

Comment: this like another way of thinking. If you can't create solution in one way, maybe you should find another way only for solve task?

Comment: It's an inefficient way of thinking though that doesn't make much sense ...